# wxMaxima: how to use texput to tell tex1 how to handle strings?

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

`tex1()` seems to return all strings as follow:

```
tex1(hello);
    {\it hello}
tex1("hello");
    \mbox{ hello }
```

What variable must one use to change this handling via `texput`? e.g. if I would just like it to print strings literally? I'm using other Maxima commands (like `printf` and `concat` to produce strings that are then passed to `tex1`, and occasionally the default handling is causing issues.

I tried `texput(""", ...)` and `texput("''", ...)`; the first wasn't accepted, the 2nd was, but did not change the output. I really have no clue for the non-quoted strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's be careful to distinguish symbols from strings. When you enter `tex1(hello)` then `hello` is a symbol, and when you enter `tex1("hello")` then `"hello"` is a string. Symbols are essentially names for items in a lookup table, which can store additional info (symbol properties) for each. Strings on the other hand are just (from Maxima's point of view) just a sequence of characters.

Anyway changing the output for all symbols or all strings is unfortunately not possible via `texput`. But with a one-line Lisp function, one can accomplish it. Try this: for symbols,

```
:lisp (defun tex-stripdollar (sym) (maybe-invert-string-case (symbol-name (stripdollar sym))))
```

and for strings,

```
:lisp (defun tex-string (str) str)
```

These are going to change some existing outputs, so you'll want to try it and see if it works for you.